# Kafka reduce the no of open files as crossing 1000000

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an kafka recieving 1gb of data every min from certain events, due to which the no of files open is going above 1000000. I am not sure which setting needs to be changed to lessen this no. Can anyone guide what could be a quick fix? should i increase the log.segment.bytes=1073741824
to 10 GB to reduce no of files getting created , or increase log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 to 15 mins so less get checked for deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the size of the segments will reduce number of files maintained by the broker, with the tradeoffs being that only closed segments are ones that get cleaned or compacted.

The other alternative is to reconsider what types of data you're using. For example, if sending files or other large binary blobs, consider using filesystem URIs rather than push the whole data through a topic